# How can I serve a .json file from the web folder without CORS problems?

Tags: htaccess, cors

I have a .json file that I want to place somewhere in my web folder and serve this if my frontend (another domain) requests it. I can open the file directly but not
The problem is, that now I run into CORS problems.
Normally if I return something in an action I can set the Headers and the Allow-Origin settings within my php file, but here I just want to get the .json file, nothing else.

I think I need to adjust the .htaccess file within my `web` directory but so far I was not successful.

I tried adding:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

within `/web/.htaccess`

Thank you for any hints how I can solve this problem.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header add Content-Type "application/json"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Auth-Token,Content-Type"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

This seems to work now, although it did not for quite some time.
I don't know why but it works now...